# Executing local file in node.js using child_process.execFile

Tags: node.js, local, child-process

I am trying to execute local file from Node.js route using `child_process.execFile`.

> File location: C:\foo\foo.bat

```
router.post('/foo1', async (req, res) => {
    let file_exe = 'foo.bat'
    execute(file_exe, [1], 'C:\\foo\\')
})

var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

function execute(fileName, params, path) {
console.log(fileName)
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  exec(fileName, params, { cwd: path }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(data);
  });
});
 return promise;
}
```

I am expecting command prompt open, but nothing happens.

Comment: This code, when simplified, run well in Node 10.15 and Windows 10.

Comment: var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

let file_exe = 'foo.bat';
execute(file_exe, [1], 'C:\\foo\\');


function execute(fileName, params, path) {

  exec(fileName, params, { cwd: path }, (err, data) => {
      console.log('good');
  });

}

Comment: @CharlieH. I updated my Node to 10.16. Copied your code into my route. Still nothing happens when executed. Windows 10.

Comment: Do you realize that if your batch file just runs and completes, you may not see a command window?  Put a `pause` into your batch file (as a test) and then see if you see the command window.  Or redirect some output to a file and then check if the file is created.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks

Comment: @jfriend00. It works now on localhost. But not working when deployed. Is it possible to have this functionality with app deployed on the web? Thanks

Comment: You do realize that the batch file runs on your server, right?  Not on the browser's computer.  It is not possible for your server to run batch files on the client.  That would be the world's worst security hole if possible.  And, it would only run properly on  your server if your deployed server was Windows too.

Comment: @jfriend00.  I do. Is there a way to run it on client computers? It's an app meant for just several people. I can make sure they have executable file placed locally.

Comment: No.  You can never run batch files on the client computer via a browser app unless you write and have the user install a custom browser plugin.  Plain browsers never have the ability to run an arbitrary file on the local user's computer.

Comment: @jfriend00. I see. Same deal with .exe?

Comment: Same deal with running any external program.

Comment: @jfriend00 When I pointed out in your deleted answer that `execFile` works in OPs scenario which you claimed otherwise, you asked me why I'm not engaging the OP or write my own answer. Why can't I point out fallacy in your answer? Is that because you have 400+K and I don't? Is that how SO suppose to work?

Comment: @CharlieH - No, I just meant that if you have information relevant to the OP, you should share it with the OP in comments to their question or an answer.  And, that was with the context that I was about the delete my answer because it was no longer relevant so the comments you had there would likely not be visible to the OP and thus would be of no help to them.  Nothing at all to do with reputation levels.  In this case, I based an answer on the node.js doc which was wrong and therefore so was my answer.  I'm wrong sometimes.  Just trying to help.

Comment: @CharlieH - It turns out the real issue here is apparently that the OP wants to run a batch file on the browser's computer which is a non-starter from node.js or from a regular web page in a browser so the question is pretty flawed too since `execFile()` runs on the server, not on the client's computer.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't ask about this right away - but later thought I should. Matter solved. Thank you very much,